# PBEKeySpec not generating desired output key length

Tags: java, android, encryption

I'm using the following code, in order to generate a hash for a provided password:

```
 public static SecretKey generateKey( String passphraseOrPin ) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    final int iterations = 10000;

    // Generate a 256-bit key
    final int outputKeyLength = 256;

    char[] chars = new char[passphraseOrPin.length()];
    passphraseOrPin.getChars( 0, passphraseOrPin.length(), chars, 0 );
    byte[] salt = "thisSaltIsInClient".getBytes();

    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance( "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1" );
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec( chars, salt, iterations, outputKeyLength );
    return secretKeyFactory.generateSecret( keySpec );
}
```

So when I get bytes from the generated password, and cast them to a String:

```
    String passwordEncrypted = Base64.encodeToString( bytesPass, Base64.DEFAULT );
```

The output is something like:

> yo2NDJ96VYadiP2jpzL3p+LW0b4qkdWS++WqAm0W9d8=

Shouldn't it be longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it has exactly the length you specified in `outputKeyLength`:

```
$ echo 'yo2NDJ96VYadiP2jpzL3p+LW0b4qkdWS++WqAm0W9d8=' | base64 --decode | hexdump -C
00000000  ca 8d 8d 0c 9f 7a 55 86  9d 88 fd a3 a7 32 f7 a7  |.....zU......2..|
00000010  e2 d6 d1 be 2a 91 d5 92  fb e5 aa 02 6d 16 f5 df  |....*.......m...|
00000020
```

or

```
$ echo 'yo2NDJ96VYadiP2jpzL3p+LW0b4qkdWS++WqAm0W9d8=' | base64 --decode | wc
0       2      32
```

(NB: 256bit = 32byte)

Comment: I guess I didn't sleep good enough today. My brain decided to ignore that bytes != bits